# Exporting table from PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, export

I'm currently facing a problem about exporting my table or database from phpmyadmin. In here is the result :

[image]

And this is my phpmyadmin vers :

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you want from us? We cannot solve your network issues from here

Comment: Is your database remote (on another PC) or are you doing all this on one PC

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No It's just on one pc

Comment: I want to download the file from exporting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running through the same problem and apparently there's a compatibility issue with the latest phpmyadmin version and PHP version. A good workaround I found is by downloading using IDM. You can choose to download it as a zipped file from the output tab in the export page to help download it by IDM.

Comment: I think it might be helpful for my problem, but is there anyway to download it without any use of download manager ?. Thank you BTW. I will try it later.